# Retrieve data from two tables sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-optimization

I am having 2 tables named table1, table2.
table1 columns are t1_id, t1_name, t1_status.
table2 columns are t1_id, t2_id, t2_name, t2_status.
When I do Some operation in frontend t1_id will be inserted into table2.
**What I need is I want t1_id(s) from table1 which are not alloted or inserted in table2.**

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT t1.t1_id, t1.t1_name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.t1_id != t2.t1_id
```

The problem with query is when all t1_id(s) are inserted into table2, then all t1_id(s) are showing again.
How to resolve this issue? *(I'am new to sql so please don't consider my mistakes.)*

Comment: see "Left Excluding JOIN" at this reference http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins , & as you are new to SQL keep this reference handy

Answer (score 1):

Use is null to get rows from table1 which don't have any associations in table2

```
SELECT t1.t1_id, t1.t1_name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
WHERE t2.t1_id IS NULL
```

Comment: one hopes that t1.id is already unique and hence selecting distinct is redundant in that case

Comment: @Used_By_Already yes updated if there is no association then there will be no chance for duplicates

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right, this must b the query you need:

```
SELECT t1.t1_id, t1.t1_name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
where t2.t1_id is null
```

Comment: @chikku if it helps, you should accept  on of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your questions: [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table)

```
SELECT t1.t1_id, t1.t1_name
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1    --it's not so relevant what you put here
FROM table2 t2 
WHERE t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
)
```

I hope this helps. ;-)

Comment: You should mark the question as duplicate and not copy the solution.